# Get x highest values from an array including identical values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the following code to retrieve the highest 3 numbers from an array.

```
$a = array(1,2,5,10,15,20,10,15);
arsort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);
$highest = array_slice($a, 0, 3);
```

This code correctly gives me the highest three numbers `array(20,15,10)`; however, I'm interested in getting the highest 3 numbers including the ones that are identical. In this example, I'm expecting to get an array like `array(10, 10, 15, 15, 20)`

Comment: `array_clice` must be a typo though. Anyway, your code will return `1,2,5` and not `20,15,10` as per the [PHP array_slice function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) ^^

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be simpler but my brain is tired. Use `arsort()` to get the highest first, count the values to get unique keys with their count and slice the first 3 (make sure to pass `true` to preserve keys):

```
arsort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);
$counts = array_slice(array_count_values($a), 0, 3, true);
```

Then loop those 3 and fill an array with the number value the number of times it was counted and merge with the previous result:

```
$highest = array();

foreach($counts as $value => $count) {
    $highest = array_merge($highest, array_fill(0, $count, $value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
$a = array(1,2,5,10,15,20,10,15); //-- Original Array

function get3highest($a){
  $h = array(); //-- highest
  if(count($a) >= 3){ //-- Checking length
    $c = 0; //-- Counter
    while ($c < 3 || in_array($a[count($a)-1],$h) ){ //-- 3 elements or repeated value
      $max = array_pop($a);
      if(!in_array($max,$h)){
        ++$c;
      }
      $h[] = $max;
    }
    sort($h); //-- sorting
  }
  return $h; //-- values
} 
print_r(get3Highest($a));
```

Of course you can improve this function to accept a dinamic value of "highest" values.

Answer (score 0):

The below function may be usefull

```
$a = array(1,2,5,10,15,20,10,15);
function getMaxValue($array,$n){ 
    $max_array = array(); // array to store all the max values
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){ // loop to get number of highest values 
        $keys = array_keys($array,max($array));  // get keys
        if(is_array($keys)){ // if keys is array 
            foreach($keys as $v){  // loop array
                $max_array[]=$array[$v];  // set values to max_array
                unset($array[$v]);  // unset the keys to get next max value 
            }
        }else{ // if not array
            $max_array[]=$array[$keys]; // set values to max_array
            unset($array[$keys]); // unset the keys to get next max value
        }

    }
    return $max_array;
}
$g = getMaxValue($a,3);
```

Out Put:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 10
)
```

You can modify it to add conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a couple of other possibilities.

**First one:**

1. Find the lowest of the top three values

   ```
   $min = array_slice(array_unique($a, SORT_NUMERIC), -3)[0];
   ```
2. Filter out any lower values

   ```
   $top3 = array_filter($a, function($x) use ($min) { return $x >= $min; });
   ```
3. Sort the result

   ```
   sort($top3);
   ```

Advantages: less code
Disadvantages: less inefficient (sorts, iterates the entire array, sorts the result)

**Second one:**

1. Sort the array in reverse order

   ```
   rsort($a);
   ```
2. Iterate the array, appending items to your result array until you've appended three distinct items.

   ```
   $n = 0;
   $prev = null;
   $top = [];

   foreach ($a as $x) {
       if ($x != $prev) $n++;
       if ($n > 3) break;
       $top[] = $x;
       $prev = $x;
   }
   ```

Advantages: more efficient (sorts only once, iterates only as much as necessary)
Disadvantages: more code

This gives the results in descending order. You can optionally use `array_unshift($top, $x)` instead of `$top[] = $x;` to get it in ascending order, but I think I've read that `array_unshift` is less efficient because it reindexes the array after each addition, so if optimization is important it would probably be better to just use `$top[] = $x;` and then iterate the result in reverse order.